# Scroll 3/4 of the page with PgDn PgUp bindings

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to configure how much the document is scrolled when page down/up are pressed?
Currently it scrolls leaving only the bottom line visible at the top, I'd like it to scroll only 3/4 of the page or so.